# Visual Studio - Access to the path '/Users/.local/share/NuGet' is denied when adding Nuget package to the project in MacOs

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I am using Visual Studio 2019 in macOS for .net Core development.

When I tried to add Nuget package, I encounter below error

```
Visual Studio - Access to the path '/Users/CCCC/.local/share/NuGet' is denied
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of this error is because `NuGet` folder does not be created automatically.
 After I create the folder myself, it works.